# Wipe Everything on Ubuntu Server except for OS

Tags: server, upgrade, ssh

Upgrading a physical server (not VM) from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 over an SSH connection, and after I do so, I need to clear off all files except for the OS and the SSH server.

Option 1: Is there a switch or parameter change that I add to the upgrade process "sudo do-release-upgrade" to wipe as it installs?

Option 2: Is there a separate set of commands I can run PRIOR to the 18.04 upgrade that will clear everything?

Option 2: Is there a separate set of commands I can run AFTER the 18.04 upgrade that will clear everything?

Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "System Restore" or "System Reset" feature. It generally has not needed one for several reasons. We can help you better if you clarify a bit more what you want to remove: User data? Deb packages? Snap Packages? Manually compiled/installed software? You're not sure? How remote is this server? Can it wait until you happen to be present? (That's much easier)

Comment: We are unable to access the server physically. Ideally, we would just do a clean 18.04 install, but that's not an option.

I am trying to create the same end result, but we are forced to do it remotely.

Comment: Since we don't know what's been installed on the server, you're asking for a long list of hypotheticals -- most of which probably won't apply. Help us to help you: Give us more information about this system's usage and history. Please [improve your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1253427/edit) instead of using comments. Comments are not intended for conversation.